# Redundant changes in new migration

Tags: doctrine-orm, migration, mariadb, symfony4

Each time I create a new migration, there are the changes I want, but there are also some changes that shouldn't be there. They are the same in each new migration.

So if I create a new migration without any changes, only those undesirable changes will be there. If I run the migration, and make a new one, those changes will be still here. I probably did something wrong, I'd like to "clean", in order to stop deleting those changes manually each time.

I'm in a project running Symfony 4.2.3 with Doctrine ORM v2.6.3, on MariaDB 10.3.14.

So here's a migration which should be empty :

```php
final class Version20190412133855 extends AbstractMigration
{
    // ...

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE player CHANGE race_id race_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE team_id team_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE country_id country_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE birthdate birthdate DATE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE clan_war CHANGE winner_id winner_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE team CHANGE country_id country_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE manager manager VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE coach coach VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE website website VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE map CHANGE tileset_id tileset_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game CHANGE map_id map_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE winner_id winner_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game RENAME INDEX idx_7a5bc50553c55f64 TO IDX_232B318C53C55F64');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE clan_war CHANGE winner_id winner_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game CHANGE map_id map_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE winner_id winner_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE game RENAME INDEX idx_232b318c53c55f64 TO IDX_7A5BC50553C55F64');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE map CHANGE tileset_id tileset_id INT DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE player CHANGE race_id race_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE team_id team_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE country_id country_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE birthdate birthdate DATE DEFAULT \'NULL\'');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE team CHANGE country_id country_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE manager manager VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'NULL\' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, CHANGE coach coach VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'NULL\' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, CHANGE website website VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'NULL\' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
    }
}
```

All those "changes" are actually already done in the database.
There is an other small problem: the generated query `ALTER TABLE game RENAME INDEX idx_7a5bc50553c55f64 TO IDX_232B318C53C55F64` which is invalid for MariaDB. If I don't delete this query, I'll get a syntax error.
And like I said: if I delete this one, the migration will run without any problems, but the same new migration will appear if I create a new one.

In an other project with the same configuration, if I make a new migration without any changes, I get an expected `[WARNING] No database changes were detected.`. If I make one change, I'll get just the change I want.
I maybe did something wrong in the annotations in my entities, so in case, here's one of the model (player) : https://pastebin.com/1mUPP3i3

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you run `php bin/console doc:sch:val`, do you get 2 "OK" messages? If the first is OK, then your entities are fine. If the second is "OK" the database is in sync with your entity configuration. If the latter is _not_ in sync, you'll get migrations ...

Comment: Hello, first thanks for this useful command I didn't know. So my entities are okay, and indeed, the Database part has an error: saying my database schema is not sync with the current mapping file. When I run `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` I get those redundant queries.
I tried to run those with `doctrine:schema:update --force` but I get a syntax error from MariaDB for the index rename query. I'll try to find a way, thanks!

Comment: Have a check manually, you should find those changes are actually necessary to pull the database in line with the changes to your business model (entities). Mind however, some changes can occur due to updates (e.g. to DoctrineModule), think in the past 2 months there was an update to make all index id letters uppercase, which also re-calculates hashes, e.g.: `RENAME INDEX idx_7a5bc50553c55f64 TO IDX_232B318C53C55F64`.

Comment: As for MariaDB support, read this bit: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/configuration.html#automatic-platform-version-detection and make sure you get to the last line ;-) Might help (also, might not, but can't hurt): `If you are running a MariaDB database, you should prefix the serverVersion with mariadb- (ex: mariadb-10.2.12).`

Comment: Indeed, now it works! Should have read less Google and more official documentation. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: All good, enjoy. Make sure to post a small answer about what solved it for you and accept it when you can ;)

Comment: @rkeet how/why does `php bin/console doc:sch:val` check the entities and the database? I couldn't find any explanation on it in Doctrine's documentation.

Comment: @Doesitmatter It's a Symfony defined alias for Doctrine command `doctrine orm:validate-schema`, see [all Doctrine commands here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html). [Specific validate-schema command](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation). Also, using the Symfony console (`php bin/console` in SF project) you can "shorten" commands to min 3 chars per section. Full command: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`.

Comment: @Doesitmatter see all commands available in your Symfony project by running `php bin/console` in your CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @rkeet:

I checked what was wrong with the Mapping and the Database with the command `doc:sch:val`.

Then for the `RENAME INDEX` syntax error case on MariaDB , I changed the server version in the Doctrine Configuration (in my case in Doctrine.yaml)
From `server_version: '5.7'` to `server_version: mariadb-10.3.14` (check your current mariadb version with `mysql --version`).